# How to get List<T> in converter class wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to use the converter, but I don't know how to get a class-side list of converters.

In my ViewModel, I have two ObservableCollections, the Customers collection to bind my DataGrid item sources and the Sectors collection to bind the converter.

```
public ObservableCollection<Custormer> Customers = new ObservableCollection<Customer>();

public ObservableCollection<Sector> Sectors = new ObservableCollection<Sector>();
```

My XAMl code look like this

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="Binding Customers" .... >
   <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name">
      <DataGridTextColumn.Binding>
         <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource ConverterNameHere}">
            <Binding Path="Name" />
            <Binding Path="Sectors" />
         </MultiBinding>
      </DataGridTextColumn.Binding>
   .....
</DataGrid>
```

My Converter:

```
public class ConverterNameHere: IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        string Name = values[0].ToString();

        /* This does not work ---------------------------- */

        ObservableCollection<Sector> SectorsList = new ObservableCollection<Sector>(values[1].ToList());

        /* ----------------------------------------------- */

        var found = SectorsList .FirstOrDefault(sector => sector.Name == Name);

        if(found == null)
        {
            return "Not Found";
        }
        return Name;
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? As far as I can see, there's no need for the ```ObservableCollection```. Just use ```values[1].ToList().FirstOrDefault(...)``` directly. You might as well consider using ```.Contains``` or ```.Any``` instead.

Comment: Could you please include an expected outcome?  What do you want the column to look like?

Comment: @imsmn values[1].TiList() does not work for me, the error msg : " object doas not contain a definition for ToList

Comment: @GeorgeKerwood the main objective of the converter is to check whether the name already exists in the list of sectors or not, if so the converter returns this name, otherwise returns "not found".

Comment: `values` is an array of objects. So it does not know the actual type, and therefor you can't call `ToList()` on on of its values. So just cast it `((IEnumerable<Sectors>)values[1]).ToList()`. However it's up to you to make sure that `values[1]` contains that type, otherwise you could also do a check `if (values[1] is IEnumerable<Sectors> sectors) { ...use sectors here...}`

Comment: Perhaps you could share the `Customer` model? Since that is your `ItemsSource`. You are currently binding to `Name` and `Sectors` as properties of `Customer`, is this your intention?

Comment: @GeorgeKerwood Sectors  is not a property of the Customer, I just want to send it with the property Customer (Name)

Comment: @AdemElAwity, that what I'm trying to explain. You have set `ItemsSource` to be a collection of `Customer`. Subsequently, all your column bindings will look for the paths relative to a `Customer`, e.g. `Customer.Name`, `Customer.Sectors`. Your `Sectors` collection will not be being passed to your converter currently, that combined with what @Knoop is explaining. Please A. Explain what you want to apear in the column "Name", and share the definition of `Customer` and `Sector`. Then I hope to be able to answer you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use pattern matching `is`

```csharp
public class ConverterNameHere : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (values[0] is string name && values[1] is ObservableCollection<Sector> sectors)
        {
            return sectors.Any(sector => sector.Name == name) ? name : "Not Found";
        }
        return null;
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return new object[] { value, null };
    }
}
```

Also you may fix the xaml because `Sectors` located in `Window.DataContext`, not in `DataGrid`'s item where `Name` is located. `Binding.Path` is relative to `DataContext`.

```xaml
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Customers}" .... >
   <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name">
      <DataGridTextColumn.Binding>
         <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource ConverterNameHere}">
            <Binding Path="Name" />
            <Binding Path="DataContext.Sectors" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}" Mode="OneWay" />
         </MultiBinding>
      </DataGridTextColumn.Binding>
   .....
</DataGrid>
```

And don't forget to put the converter to `Resources`

```xaml
<Window.Resources>
    <local:ConverterNameHere x:Key="ConverterNameHere"/>
</Window.Resources>
```

Comment: Why not take a little time to explain "fix the xaml"? Having multiple datacontext is quite an important part of the understanding. Also even the fact for this to work he'll need to assign his `Sectors` was the  `Window` data context.

Comment: @GeorgeKerwood fixed.

Comment: @aepot Thanks, that's exactly what I need

Comment: @GeorgeKerwood Thank your for your time :)